# Are there any guidelines for the "IBM Premier Level Business Partner"?

Tags: db2

Our company currently subcontracts a DB2 project to a company which have "IBM Premier Level Business Partner". I was just wondering, are there any guideline about what they should provide (say, [SQAP](http://www.shellmethod.com/refs/SQAP.pdf), source code....) as an IBM partner?

I ask this because we are not too familiar with database development and the db contract terms. Therefore, we may want to make sure of what we should have after the contract is finished.

Thanks~

Sorry, it may not be a suitable place for not programming related question, please suggest me a suitable place if I'm posted wrong.

Comment: A much better place to ask this would be to check with IBM directly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if what you are looking for is stated in some place. The closest thing could be PartnerWorld in IBM: https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_home_pub_index

I think a partner is just people close to IBM, with a lot of IBM product knowledge, but they can do almost whatever they want with the client, they just have to follow some criteria based of sells, courses, etc. This is the reason, there is a big competence between partners.

Comment: You need certain amount of "points" from certifications and similar per year to maintain a Business Partner status.